# How can I replicate the style of the quotes in Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming"?

Tags: quoting, knuth

How can I replicate the style of the quotes in Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming"?

I mean the quotes found at the beginning and at the end of each chapter, for example see the following one which is a one-liner:

[image]

or the following which spans more than one line:

[image]

Comment: You have the `epigraph` package.

Comment: Knuth uses plain TeX, not LaTeX.  These look like the quotes in the TeXbook, and those are defined in the file `manmac.tex`.  Under the circumstances, it's probably easier to define your own environment using `\raggedleft`.  the `epigraph` package, I believe, doesn't have quite the same style, although it's otherwise very nice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well if you literally want to replicate what Knuth did, you could use the same macros. The macros he used/uses for *The Art of Computer Programming* (TAOCP) are [available as `taocpmac.tex`](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/local/lib/taocpmac.tex), and the relevant ones for the examples in the question are `\quoteformat` and `\author`. Download `taocpmac.tex`, comment out the `\input figdir.local` line at the top (or create a file of that name) and do something like:

```
\input taocpmac

\beginchapter CHAPTER SIX: SEARCHING.

{\quoteformat{Let's look at the record.}
\author AL SMITH (1928)
}

\medskip

The normal text of the chapter here.

\bigskip

{\quoteformat{I shall have accomplished my purpose if I have sorted out and put in logical order
the gist of the great volume of material which has been generated about sorting
over the past few years.}
\author J. C. HOSKEN (1955)
}

\bye
```

Compile it with `tex` or `pdftex` (or `xetex` or `luatex`, i.e. not any `*latex`):

[image: result]

If you don't want to pull in all of `taocpmac.tex` you could copy over just the relevant macros, and you can even dress them up in superficially LaTeX-ish clothing if you prefer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\font\eightss=cmssq8
\font\eightssi=cmssqi8
\newcommand\quoteAuthorDate[3]{\begingroup
  \baselineskip 10pt
  \parfillskip 0pt
  \interlinepenalty 10000 % not needed in example
  \leftskip 0pt plus 40pc minus \parindent
  \let\rm=\eightss
  \let\sl=\eightssi
  \everypar{\sl}#1\par
  \nobreak\smallskip
  \noindent\rm--- #2\unskip\enspace(#3)\par
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}
\hsize = 6in %  Wider than default, to illustrate.

\quoteAuthorDate{Let's look at the record.}{AL SMITH}{1928}

\medskip

The normal text of the chapter here.

\bigskip

\quoteAuthorDate{I shall have accomplished my purpose if I have sorted out and put in logical order\par
the gist of the great volume of material which has been generated about sorting\par
over the past few years.}{J. C. HOSKEN}{1955}

\medskip

\end{document}
```

Adjust the skips and line breaks as desired. Although you may get something passable even without manually chosen breaks, DEK chooses the line breaks manually — that's the reason the definition of `\quoteformat` has `\obeylines` in it, and my “LaTeX” example above has `\par`s in the second quote. LaTeX users tend not to like such things. If you're in the same category, you can try to find a LaTeX package that does what you want. For example, as mentioned in the comments on the question, you can use [`epigraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}

\epigraph{Let's look at the record.}{AL SMITH (1928)}

The normal text of the chapter here.

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\epigraph{I shall have accomplished my purpose if I have sorted out and put in logical order
the gist of the great volume of material which has been generated about sorting
over the past few years.}{J. C. HOSKEN (1955)}

\end{document}
```

but the appearance isn't the same as in TAOCP.

---

Historical appendix: How do we know that this is how DEK enters the quotes, besides the fact that these macros exist in `taocpmac.tex`?

Well actually I don't know about the surrounding `{` and `}`, but as for the rest (`\quoteformat` and `\author`), in fact this is something that hasn't change substantially since the very first “design doc” that DEK wrote for TeX back in May 1977, before a single line of the TeX program had been written. In these (TEXDR.AFT and TEX.ONE, published in *Digital Typography*) he wrote down what he'd like to type as input, and it's basically the same. Later, the older TeX manual (e.g. the one published in *TeX and METAFONT: New Directions in Typesetting*) actually went into great detail on how the input to TAOCP was done, in its “Appendix E: Example of a Book Format” where these macros were in a file called `acphdr.TEX` at the time, and it even says “For quotations you type ...” and gives `\quoteformat` and `\author`. (The current *TeXbook* in its “Appendix E: Example Formats” instead explains `manmac.tex` which is used to typeset *The TeXbook* itself, and you can also look at how quotes are done in `texbook.tex`) There's also mention of `acpmac.tex` in [this TUG 1995 interview](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-1/tb50knut.pdf), and finally it's now called `taocpmac.tex.`

Comment: Thanks for such a complete historical exposition.

Comment: I tested with success your first source. I downloaded http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/local/lib/taocpmac.tex and I just needed to create a file with name `figdir.local` with this content `\def\figdir{/home/acp/figs}`; after that, I compiled with `tex` and `pdftex`. I am on `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
` and `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
`.

Comment: I believe the fact that the line breaks are done manually is mentioned in one of the Mathematical Writing lectures. One of the students asks how he got them to look so nice and he said that doing it manually was the best/only way, or something to that effect.

Comment: @texdr.aft Searching for it found this: *As a final parenthetical remark, he told us about the way that the (quite long) captions for illustrations in SA are typeset: The linebreaks are determined by hand. The final line always ends at the right margin (there’s no extra white space). To achieve this, the SA copy editors must count letters and reword the captions until they fit. One of the methods that they use to make things fit nicely is to start at the end of the caption and start removing ‘the’s. (“It is not placed at root of tree because it is too far from center of alphabet.”) [1977]* :-)